# iOS - subivew can't be centered in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

It's really weird.
No matter how I set the constraints, it just ignors all of them after layouts.
I've tried to use `cell.indicator.center = cell.center` and `cell.indicator.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]` in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`
but still not worked.
Is there any special way to center a subview inside a `UITableViewCell`?

LoadingCell.xib

[image]

Screenshot(Simulator)

[image]

updated:

After trying @Vibha Singh's advice, I put these codes in my `LoadingCell`.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    print("layoutSubviews")
    print(center)
    print(contentView.bounds)
    indicator.center = contentView.center
}
```

And it printed these lines:

```
layoutSubviews
(207.0, 1055.16668891907)
(0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 44.6666666666667)
```

But the indicator is still not centered.

updated:

I fixed it by creating a new cell with an indicator.
Both of them have exactly the same constraints. The new one is centered as expected, but the old one is still positioned at left top.

updated:

I did use centerX and centerY as constraints at the first time. But it's not worked. So I have to try another way. That's why I use so many constraints in the first screenshot.

Here are the screenshots with two exactly the same xibs.

Both of them use the same codes to dequeue.

```
let dequeue = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SharedCell.loading.rawValue, for: indexPath)

if let cell = dequeue as? CenterLoadingCell {
    cell.indicator.startAnimating()
}
else if let cell = dequeue as? LoadingCell {
    cell.indicator.startAnimating()
}

return dequeue
```

The first one is named `LoadingCell`, which is not centered on the simulator.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The second one is named `CenterLoadingCell`, which I created after I asked this question. And this one is centered on the simulator.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add more information about the constraints you are using? settings the center in `cellForRow` will not work, since there is more layouting done after that

Comment: try it using `cell.indicator.center = cell.contentView?.center` insted of using `cell.indicator.center = cell.center`

Comment: @CatalinaT. You can see all the constraints in the first image.

Comment: add only two constrains on indicator centreX and centreY and remove all other constraints no need to do anything else

Comment: @PramodKumar Still not works.

Comment: just add only two constraint, remove all constraint  and code to centre it

Comment: @PramodKumar It did only have those two constrains at first time. But it's not centered. So I tried another way to see if it worked. That's why it looks like this now.

Comment: If it still not working then check the frame of table view , is it at the right position in the container view?

Comment: I´d use the view inspector layout to see where is the superview. The indicator will use the constraints relative to that superview. Remove all the not needed constraints and add the centerX and centerY. It has to work

Comment: @KimiChiu - it sounds like you are doing way too much. Is there a reason you want to create your cell in a xib and not as a prototype cell in your storyboard?

Comment: @DonMag I want my cell can be reused in different TableViewControllers rather than create it multiple times.

Comment: Just put 

indicator.center = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.bounds.midX), y: CGFloat(self.bounds.midY))

Comment: @ Vibha Singh I've tried this one but still not works. Looks like the position is correct, but the indicator just don't move to there.

Comment: Just use auto layout?! Why is this hard? Centre vertically, centre horizontally. Done. Don't mess around with the frame or with auto layout masks. Just add two constraints. Delete the four constraints that you have for top, leading, trailing, bottom. They are not required. And delete any code that you have that is trying to change the layout.

Comment: @Fogmeister I did. I really did. And it just not works. So I have to try another way to make it centered. That's why it looks like this now. I only use centerX and centerY at the first time. And you can see that the indicator is centered in the storyboard even if I add these constraints. But it's not centered on the simulator.

Comment: @Fogmeister Just updated my question with multiple screenshots. You can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing your layout setting big time by adding unnecessary constraints. Check this implementation.

[image: Image with Constraint]

With Custom Cell:
[image]

Comment: Tried. I did use these constraints at first time. But it's not working. So I tried another way to see if it works.

Comment: I have tried custom cell implementation too check another screenshot attached.

Comment: Just created another cell with indicator, and only use the centerX and centerY constraints. This one is centered as expected. But the original `LoadingCell` is still not centered. Both of them have exactly the same constraints. Does that means the original `LoadingCell` have a internal problem from autolayout?

Comment: Can't say without looking at both cells but that it worked for you.

Comment: I've uploaded screenshots about these two xibs. Hope it could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add indicator like

```
  let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
                            activityView.center = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(cell.bounds.midX), y: CGFloat(cell.bounds.midY))

                            cell.contentView.addSubview(activityView)
                            activityView.startAnimating()
```

Or you can set frame in below method of cell

```
override func layoutSubviews()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it easily with constraints

```
func setConstraints(item:UIView , relatedTo:UIView , attr:NSLayoutAttribute , relatedBy:NSLayoutRelation , multiplier: CGFloat , constant : CGFloat)

{
    relatedTo.addSubview(item)
    item.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: item, attribute: attr, relatedBy: relatedBy, toItem: relatedTo, attribute: attr, multiplier: multiplier, constant: constant).isActive = true




}
```

and usage :

```
setConstraints(item: indicator, relatedTo:cell.contentView, attr:centerX, relatedBy:.equal, multiplier: 0 , constant : 0)
```